# Optimal Thruster Layout For Cubesat

Tags: propulsion, design, cubesat, rendezvous, thrust-vectoring

I am working on a simulation of a Cubesat for rendezvous. Using the Clohessy-Wiltshire equations I calculate delta-v. Now that I know the thrust needed for operation, I would like to know how to calculate the optimal placement of the thrusters for 3-axis control.

Comment: On a cubesat you probably wouldn't use thrusters for three axis control--most cubesatd don't even have a thruster. Those that do, typically only have one and use Magnetorquers or reaction wheels to adjust their attitude

Comment: Is your cubesat always in LEO where Earth's magnetic field might be used for momentum unloading of reaction wheels, or would they be in high orbits with minimal magnetic field, or even in interplanetary space like the MarCO cubesats are?

Comment: Definitely, one through center of mass, plus a set of reaction wheels, plus magnetorquers.